# HTML icons mapping based on data value

Tags: html, spring-boot

I am creating a weather web app based on API from *openweather.com* using Spring-Boot and Angular.
I am also using this [weather-icons](https://github.com/erikflowers/weather-icons) package.
In my HTML file weather icons are displayed like this:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
 <i class="wi wi-snow" style="font-size: 8em;"></i>
 <i id="description">{{weather.weatherID}}</i>
</div>
```

With the help of API I have also weather code value available in html.

Let's say I have a file *weather.data* with weather codes mapped to icon description like this:

```
601: snow
602: sleet
611: rain-mix
```

Is it possible to display certain icon in HTML based on value in data file?
What I want to do is something like:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <i class="wi wi-{{weatherDescription}}" style="font-size: 8em;"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: If the data file is small, as above(having just 3 records), you can go with "ng-class"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get your data from *weather.data* in a scope variable.

It would be like:

**In Controller:**

```
$http.get(path of weather.data file, null, function(response){
    $scope.weatherList = response; //do angular.fromJson if required
});
```

I hope you are getting a JSON object as :

```
$scope.weatherList = {
    601: "snow",
    602: "sleet",
    611: "rain - mix"
}
```

If you are getting weather code from server side in *weatherDescription*, then you can use it like this on html :

**In Html:**

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <i class="wi wi-{{weatherList[weatherDescription]}}" style="font-size: 8em;"></i>
</div>
```

I hope this works for you.